# Python float() limitation on scientific notation

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, floating-point

- python 3.6.5
- numpy 1.14.3
- scipy 1.0.1
- cerberus 1.2

I'm trying to convert a string '6.1e-7' to a float 0.00000061 so I can save it in a mongoDb field.

My problem here is that float('6.1e-7') doesn't work (it will work for float('6.1e-4'), but not float('6.1e-5') and more).

**Python float**

I can't seem to find any information about why this happen, on [float limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), and every examples I found shows a conversion on e-3, never up to that.

**Numpy**

I installed Numpy to try the float96()/float128() ...float96() doesn't exist and float128() return a float '6.09999999999999983e-07'

**Format**

I tried 'format(6.1E-07, '.8f')' which works, as it return a string '0.00000061' but when I convert the string to a float (so it can pass [cerberus validation](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/)) it revert back to '6.1E-7'.

Any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's just two representations of the same value. Do you actually have any *problems* dealing with the float represented as `6.1e-7` (as distinct from the string `'6.1e-7'`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'6.1e-7'` is a string:

```
>>> type('6.1e-7')
<class 'str'>
```

While `6.1e-7` is a float:

```
>>> type(6.1e-7)
<class 'float'>
```

`0.00000061` is the same as `6.1e-7`

```
>>> 0.00000061 == 6.1e-7
True
```

And, internally, this float is represented by `0`'s and `1`'s. That's just yet another representation of the same float.

However, when converted into a string, they're no longer compared as numbers, they are just characters:

```
>>> '0.00000061' == '6.1e-7'
False
```

And you can't compare strings with numbers either:

```
>>> 0.00000061 == '6.1e-7'
False
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it doesn't matter. I assumed it will be problematic to query mongoDb, but it is not. both form '0.00000061' or '6.1e-7' can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is too twisted to be precisely understood but I'll try to get some telepathy for this.

In an internal format, numbers don't keep any formatting information, neither integers nor floats do. For an integer 123, you can't restore whether it was presented as `"123"`, `"     123   "` (with tons of spaces before and after it), `000000123` or `+0123`. For a floating number, `0.1`, `+0.0001e00003`, `1.000000e-1` and myriads of other forms can be used. Internally, all they shall result in the same number.

(There are some specifics with it when you use IEEE754 "decimal floating", but I am sure it is not your case.)

When saving to a database, internal representation stops having much sense. Instead, the database specifics starts playing role, and it can be quite different. For example, SQL suggests using column types like `numeric(10,4)`, and each value will be converted to decimal format corresponding to the column type (typically, saved on disk as text string, with or without decimal point). In MongoDB, you can keep a floating value either as JSON number (IEEE754 `double`) or as text. Each variant has its own specifics, but, if you choose text, it is your own responsibility to provide proper formatting each time you form this text. You want to see a fixed-point decimal number with 8 digits after point? OK, no problems: you just shall format according to `%.8f` on each preparing of such representation.

The issues with representation selection are:

1. Uniqueness: no different forms should be available for the same value. Otherwise you can, for example, store the same contents under multiple keys, and then mistake older one for a last one.
2. Ordering awareness: DB should be able to provide natural order of values, for requests like "ceiling key-value pair".

If you always format values using `%.8f`, you will reach uniqueness, but not ordering. The same for `%.g`, `%.e` and really other text format except special (not human readable) ones that are constructed to keep such ordering. If you need ordering, just use numbers as numbers, and don't concentrate on how they look like in text forms.

(And, your problem is not tied with numpy.)